# Read jpeg metadata asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, metadata, jpeg, exif

I am trying to read exif metadata such as title, description, and date from a jpg file while implementing a website with asp.net core 3.1. Previously I had done this with the BitmapMetadata class which is not available in asp.net core. I have tried the ExifLib and ExifLib.Standard NuGet packages without success.

On the Razor page, I have

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="FormFile"></label>
    <input asp-for="FormFile" class="form-control-file" type="file" />
  </div>
  <input accept="image/jpeg" asp-page-handler="LoadInfo" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Load Info" />
</form>
```

In the model for the Razor page, I have

```
public IFormFile FormFile { get, set }
public string NewPhotoCaption { get, set }
public string NewPhotoDescription { get, set }
public DateTime NewPhotoDate { get, set }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLoadInfoAsync()
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     using (ExifReader reader = new ExifReader(FormFile.OpenReadStream()))
     {
       reader.GetTagValue(ExifTags.XPTitle, out string newPhotoCaption);
       NewPhotoCaption = newPhotoCaption;
       reader.GetTagValue(ExifTags.XPDescription, out string newPhotoDescription);
       NewPhotoDescription = newPhotoDescription;
       reader.GetTagValue(ExifTags.DateTime, out DateTime newPhotoDate);
       NewPhotoDate = newPhotoDate;
     }
   }
   return Page();
 }
```

The output parameters of the reader.GetTagValue method are always null. I am successfully instantiating the FormFile property as I can read the filename, length, etc (code not shown).

Answer (score 3):

I was able to read the jpeg metadata from a file using the SixLabors.ImageSharp NuGet package.

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Metadata.Profiles.Iptc;

public string NewPhotoCaption { get; set; }
public string NewPhotoDescription { get; set; }
public DateTime? NewPhotoDate { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLoadInfoAsync()
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Image image = Image.Load(FormFile.OpenReadStream());
    List<IptcValue> nameValues = image.Metadata.IptcProfile.GetValues(IptcTag.Name);
    if (nameValues.Count > 0)
    {
     NewPhotoCaption = nameValues[0].Value;
    }      

    List<IptcValue> captionValues = image.Metadata.IptcProfile.GetValues(IptcTag.Caption);
    if (captionValues.Count > 0)
    {
      NewPhotoDescription = captionValues[0].Value;
    }

    string dateString;
    DateTime newPhotoDate;
    List<IptcValue> dateValues = 
      Image.Metadata.IptcProfile.GetValues(IptcTag.CreatedDate);
    if (dateValues.Count > 0)
    {
      dateString = dateValues[0].Value;
      if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
        dateString,
        "yyyyMMdd",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out newPhotoDate))
      {
        NewPhotoDate = newPhotoDate;
      }
      else
      {
        NewPhotoDate = null;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      NewPhotoDate = null;
    }
   return Page();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.